# Solar power, Battery power to mains voltage

Tags: electrical-engineering, solar-energy

My question is what is the most efficient way to convert 48V D.C. to 220V A.C. Not the easiest or most cost efficient but the most efficient electrically?

Also if anyone has any cheats on the best way to resupply LED House light fittings that were originally 220v supply to 48V dc I would be grateful.

Comment: An inverter, but planning lights for a tiny house and we are looking at 12v bulbs to put into fittings...

Comment: @Solar Mike with an Inverter (tried 2 different ones and they were about the same). I get about 50% losses so it really messes the batteries around. I also have no light bulbs all the lights are led type fittings not LED bulbs, hence my question for an easy cheat to power them directly with DC. It is ridiculous I can run around in my electric trike for a month on a charge I cannot run the house lights and the P.C for 2 days. And the battery set for the house is larger than the Trike.

Comment: Sounds like you do pedal assist on the Trike...

Comment: No pedals it's like a little truck, it has a drop down ramp at the back and I use it for taking the wheelie bin to the dump as well as for shopping and going fishing. Since I had that it has made me realise how bad the solar set up is.

Comment: So what size inverter? if you are running a 8kW inverter for 60W of lights then poor efficiency is normal.

Comment: What mike said - [link](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/eme812/node/738)

Comment: If you want to power light fixtures and be compliant wrt EMI/RFI requirements for the downstream fixtures, you will need to supply them with true sine wave 220 VAC from the inverter. The requitements for The inverter itself vary, but class B would be minimum and usual for something like a job site trailer. Class A would be the norm for RV, and pretty much required for boats if you want the Nav systems to work. So you want a decent Class A true sine wave converter sized for you loads. These generally have a high surge rating, so they can start pumps and compressors.

Comment: There are some that are high frequency switching that will have a lower surge rating and may have a slightly higher efficiency (Use CES or EU efficiency rating). Be leery of these if they have both high efficiency and Class A EMI rating. It is difficult and expensive to do both.

Comment: I am using a 3kW inverter and I have a 280 meter square house plus Garden lighting. I use solar for lights, T.V. and P.C. I could probably trim the inverter size a little I bought 3kw because of the possible need for emergency power elsewhere if we lost mains. But you are correct it will reduce loses if I reduce the size. As for the other specs thanks a lot I'll check them out. I have gone 48v on the outside lights it was easy because of them using LED bulbs. Its the house that is the problem were unless I can find a cheat I will have to continue to reconvert to 220 ac  Tks Both for your help.